# Populate VBA array, one row at a time

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to populate an array with rows of data at a time instead of element by element.  For example, I'd like to get a final product like the 3x3 array:

1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9

by populating it with the row 1 2 3, then with 4 5 6, then with 7 8 9.

In Excel, I have formulas set up in cells F1:Z1 that change based on inputs in cells A1:D1.  The macro loads the case in A1:D1, and then I want to be able to select cells F1:Z1 and insert them into an array at once, instead of looping through individual elements in F1, G1, H1, ..., Z1.  (I have 10,000 cases, so I know the array would have 10,000 rows and 21 columns.)

Is there any way to do this, or would I have to loop through each element individually?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually populate an array in one shot. Suppose your Range of interest is `A1:C200` in `Sheet1`. You can populate the array using the following

```
Dim v as Variant
v = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C200").Value
```

This will give you a 2D array with 3 columns and 200 rows.

Comment: +1. When using arrays uses `Value2` rather than `Value` , ie.  `v = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C200").Value2`. See this  [post](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/) by Charles Williams.

Comment: I know I can populate it in one shot, but that's not really what I'm looking for here.  I have one row of formulas that changes based on some inputs.  My macro cycles through each combo of inputs, and I want to be able to grab the results from the formulas and put it into the array.

Comment: To my knowledge you cannot populate a row at once, you will need to use a loop

Comment: See the example in the answer

Answer (score 0):

If any one need  help, I was looking for a solution to the same need too, and I found this right now.

Here is a solution using "Index" function :

```
Sub Test()

    Dim varArray            As Variant
    Dim varTemp             As Variant

    varArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E10")
    varTemp = Application.Index(varArray, 2, 0)

End Sub
```

In this example, varTemp contains the values of the row number "2" in the range "A1:E10".

Say we have, in the columns A, B and C, from row 1 to 10, this values :

```
1   a   q
2   b   w
3   c   e
4   d   r
5   e   t
6   f   y
7   g   u
8   h   i
9   i   o
10  j   p
```

then :

```
Debug.Print varTemp(1)
Debug.Print varTemp(2)
Debug.Print varTemp(3)
```

will display :

```
2
b
w
```

Have a look here : https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/

Answer (score 0):

You can actually store the entire row at once. I was trying to do exactly what you are doing here

Consider you have formulae in "A3:Z3" which you want to loop got 1000 times and store values. below are steps

declare a variant

```
Dim myarray(1000) As Variant
for i = 1 to 1000
    myarray(i) = Range("A3:Z3").value2
next i
```

use the same loop to paste wherever you want